# Injeção de Dependência de duas ou mais classes que implementam a mesma interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, injeção-de-dependência

Toda a arquitetura do meu sistema está baseada em injeção de dependencia,
onde no meu configureServices eu configuro as injeções da seguinte forma

services.AddScoped();

Porém surgiu a necessidade de eu ter que utilizar 2 classes que implementam 1 Interface e com base em um valor que eu passo em tempo de execução horas instancio uma classe horas outra.

Sem injeção de dependencia eu resolvia esse problema com uma factory.

Com injeção de dependencia estou tendo dificuldade uma fez que essa configuração é feita na CONFIGURESERVICES.

Como vcs costumam resolver esse problema?

Comment: um dos overloads permite que você passa uma function, que em tese permite uma factory, olha esse exemplo https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/net-core-dependency-injection-one-interface-multiple-implementation/
não testei ainda

Comment: Provavelmente o valor que você passa não é no startup da aplicação, correto? Pq se for, basta fazer uma função anomia ou até um IF. Agora se isso acontece depois, talvez vc queira injetar a factory. Mas seria legal exemplificar com código, explicar melhor o que essa classe faz etc...

Comment: O valor que eu irei passar no parametro da factory eu só terei em uma camada abaixo da WebApi onde se encontra a startup, na camada ApplicationService.

Comment: @LucasMiranda fiz uns testes e acho que seu comentário deu certo

Comment: A solução do @LucasMiranda funcionou. Muito obrigado

Comment: legal, midnight! se puder, responda a sua própria pergunta, é algo interessante e possivelmente alguém vai aparecer por aqui com essa duvida também

Comment: eu respondi @LucasMiranda mas o stackoverflow converteu em comentário e ficou desse jeito. Talvez seja interessante vc responder e ai eu confirmo como resposta correta